# Is there a workaround for getting an executable to autorun in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, executable, autorun, inf

I have an executable file I made using Python and I am trying to get it to run automatically upon being plugged in via a USB on an external drive. I've run into the issue that Windows seems to have removed that feature, but autorun is a key feature of what I am trying to create. Is there some workaround that has been found, or am I out of luck?

I tried making an INF file, here is what that looked like:

[autorun]

open=myfilename.exe

This doesn't work (meaning plugging in the USB acts as normal as opposed to starting up my executable) likely due to Windows disabling that feature past Windows 7.

One last thing is that it needs to work on any computer running Windows 10 with zero user input if at all possible. Is it time to go back to the drawing board?

Comment: How much control over the target computers do you have?

Comment: @JonSG sorry, to clarify, I meant any computer running windows 10, so theoretically, zero.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a huge security problem if one could do this?

Comment: It might be easier for users if you placed the install in Amazon S3 storage (or Auzre/Google equivalent) and sent links to the users.  User clicks link, install downloads, they click on the filename and it starts to install.  The main reasons to use USB these days are for very large installs and/or systems without an internet connection.  Bandwidth is also cheaper than buying USB sticks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been permanently revoked due to security problems. If you can find a way to do this, file a vulnerability report.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144202(v=vs.85)), autorun still works on CD-ROMs but I don't trust it at all. If it works on USB CD-ROMS expect that to be taken away.

"One last thing is that it needs to work on any computer running Windows 10 with zero user input if at all possible." We don't want this anymore. It was a good idea in 1995. It was a bad idea in 1998. It was an unacceptable risk in 2005. It's gone in 2020.